# Calling javascript function from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

Is it possible to call a JS function when a **specific** a item is selected from dropdownlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select id="menu" name="menu">
    <option value="something">Click here</option>
    <option value="nothing">Not this</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('menu').onchange = function() {
    if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value === 'something') {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

Change "something" to whatever value you want.

Comment: one more little question, with onchange event there is a problem with re-selecting same item. If I try to select the same item event, the function won't get triggered. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

HTML & JS:

```
<select id="menu" name="menu" onClick="eval(this.value);">
    <option value="func1();">Click here</option>
    <option value="func2();">Not this</option>
</select>
```

you can change 'onClick' with 'onChange' if you want.

i borrowed some code from J-P ;-)